# Flask sqlalchemy - Minimal Application

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am starting with Flask sqlalchemy, but i don't understand how works the demo of the homepage ([here](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html#a-minimal-application)).

This will create the structure:

```
>>> from yourapplication import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

But I don't understand where these users are stored.

```
>>> from yourapplication import User
>>> admin = User('admin', 'admin@example.com')
>>> guest = User('guest', 'guest@example.com')
>>> db.session.add(admin)
>>> db.session.add(guest)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

Because if I do `Select * from user;`

I will get:

```
test=# \dt
        List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner
--------+------+-------+----------
 public | user | table | postgres
(1 row)

test=# select * from user;
 current_user
--------------
 postgres
(1 row)
```

However the output is the expected:

```
>>> users = User.query.all()
>>> [<User u'admin'>, <User u'guest'>]
```

So, what is happening here? the users are stored in cache? memory? Because i don't see any admin or guest in the `user` table .

Comment: you probably are supposed to configure your database connexion somewhere (actually, I just clicked the link, it is like, in the middle of the page. `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'`)

Comment: @njzk2 'postgresql://postgres:xxx@localhost/test', If I don't set this conf, obviously the program will give an error.

Comment: not necessarily. the default sqlite path works very well.

Comment: @njzk2 ok, but the problem is not that. I have the expected output, i just want to understand where is stored the user info.

Comment: your postgresql table really does not resemble the expected schema. therefore, it is stored somewhere else. are you sure it is not in the sqlite file?

Comment: @njzk2, I am sure about that, because if I don't create the database test in PostgreSQL I will get an error.

Comment: and if you delete the `user` table, is it created by flask ?

Comment: @njzk2, no. This is so confused.. I need to create the database test,  tables are generated by flask, then i get data from somewhere. this makes no sense at all. I am using vagrant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flask is using the extremely unfortunate table name `user`. [This is a reserved keyword in the database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html); an alias for the built-in `user` function, which is in turn an alias for `current_user`. That's why you get the column-name `current_user` when you `select * from user`; you're really running the pseudo-function `current_user`.

This is made more confusing by the fact that "user" doesn't use SQL function syntax, it's undecorated, and by the fact that it's rewritten by the parser so there's no function by that name actually defined, hence the confusing outcome:

```
regress=> explain select * from user;
                             QUERY PLAN                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on "current_user"  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=64)
(1 row)
```

If you want to describe or select from the user-defined table named `user` you must, per the documentation on reserved words, quote it. So you must write:

```
select * from "user";
```

or

```
select * from public."user";
```

(schema-qualified).

Similarly:

```
\dt "user"
```

will show the table structure.

Please report a bug against Flask. It should not be using an SQL-92 reserved word as a relation name.

**EDIT**: Flask is creating a table called 'user' because the classname is User. In order to avoid this, it is recommended to provide a `__tablename__` option while defining the model.

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__= 'MyUser'
....
```

This way, you can avoid the conflicts with default conventions of the database.

Comment: @user2990084 You should report a bug against Flask. `user` has been an SQL reserved word since SQL-92. It should not be using it. At the very minimum, Flask needs to document the quirks this will cause.

Comment: @CraigRinger : the mistake is in the application using User as class name, knowing the class name is in turn used as table name (being always quoted in the library, it poses no problem). (And therefore in the flask example given. Though most people won't see this problem)

Comment: Ideally, one should overwrite the default table name by using `__tablename__` = "xyz" in order to avoid this issue. Alternatively, use a different class name that User